# Cyrillic Small Caps not working in section names

Tags: sectioning, babel, small-caps, cyrillic

I have recently encountered weird problem. Following code:

```
\documentclass[14pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[english, serbianc]{babel}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[Script=Cyrillic]{serbian}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\setmainfont{XCharter}

\begin{document}

    \begin{serbian}
        \begin{abstract}
            Чича Ђорђе жваће шљиве. Његова кћи Љиља меша џем. \textsc{АаБбВвГгДд}.
        \end{abstract}

        \section{Чича Ђорђе: \textsc{АаБбВвГгДд}.}
        Чича Ђорђе: \textsc{АаБбВвГгДд}.
    \end{serbian}

    \begin{english}
        \section{\foreignlanguage{serbian}{Чича Ђорђе: \textsc{АаБбВвГгДд}.}}
        Чича Ђорђе: \textsc{АаБбВвГгДд}.
    \end{english}

\end{document}
```

renders this result:

[image]

As you can see I'm using XChapter that have rich Cyrillic support, however, it's small caps does not work neither within serbian language environment, nor inside abstract, section names, chapter names etc. What is funny is that small caps do work inside body text inside english language environment. I tested with other fonts with good Cyrillic small caps support and same problem happens.

Does anybody have an idea what the problem might be and how can I make XeTex render XChapter small caps correctly within serbian language environment and in abstract body, section names, chapter names, etc.?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: You shouldn't load `fontenc`, but it's a minor problem. A more relevant issue is loading both `babel` and `polyglossia`: don't. However, the problem seems to be with `polyglossia`, because with `babel` the small caps letters are correctly found.

Comment: @egreg Thanks! It appears that turning off ```polyglossia``` functionality solved this issue as all seems to be correctly rendered. If you wish please post as answer so I can accept it.

Comment: I’ve improved my answer so you can get Serbian lowercase letters plus small caps in either `babel` or `polyglossia`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems an issue with `polyglossia`. By the way, you shouldn't load both it and `babel`, because they fight each other.

Also, don't load `fontenc` when using XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage[english,serbianc]{babel}

\setmainfont{XCharter}

\begin{document}

\begin{abstract}
Чича Ђорђе жваће шљиве. Његова кћи Љиља меша џем. \textsc{АаБбВвГгДд}.
\end{abstract}

\section{Чича Ђорђе: \textsc{АаБбВвГгДд}.}

Чича Ђорђе: \textsc{АаБбВвГгДд}.

\begin{otherlanguage}{english}
\section{\foreignlanguage{serbian}{Чича Ђорђе: \textsc{АаБбВвГгДд}.}}
\textsc{AbcDef}\textbf{\textsc{AbcDef}}
\end{otherlanguage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can also use `polyglossia`, if preferred, but in this case you need to help the package by defining a `\serbianfont` family (maybe also `\serbianfontsf` and `\serbianfonttt`).

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainlanguage[script=Cyrillic]{serbian}
\setotherlanguage{english}

\setmainfont{XCharter}
\newfontfamily{\serbianfont}{XCharter}

\begin{document}

\begin{abstract}
Чича Ђорђе жваће шљиве. Његова кћи Љиља меша џем. \textsc{АаБбВвГгДд}.
\end{abstract}

\section{Чича Ђорђе: \textsc{АаБбВвГгДд}.}
        Чича Ђорђе: \textsc{АаБбВвГгДд}.

\begin{otherlanguage}{english}
\section{\foreignlanguage{serbian}{Чича Ђорђе: \textsc{АаБбВвГгДд}.}}
\textsc{AbcDef}\textbf{\textsc{AbcDef}}
\end{otherlanguage}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It’s actually because they used the Babel command `\foreignlanguage{serbian}{,,,}`, but loaded Babel with the language `serbianc`, not `serbian`. So, the language is not being changed, and XCharter has special small-caps features for Cyrillic.

Comment: @Davislor That's not the source of the problem.

Comment: Thanks. I went back and solved the second problem.

Answer (score 2):

First, you’re attempting to mix the incompatible packages `polyglossia`, `fontenc` and `babel`.  You want to choose either `babel` with a legacy 8-bit encoding, `babel` with Unicode, or `Polyglossia`.

You are only getting this problem with the text within `\foreignlanguage{serbian}{...}` because you told Babel that you were using the language `serbianc`, not `serbian`.  You’re mixing up `babel` and `polyglossia` here.  As a result, the language is not being changed, so the script is still set to Latin.

When you fix that error, you have another problem: XCharter disables small caps for `Language=Serbian`.  However, if you set `Language=Default`, you get a Russian instead of Serbian б.  You want to set `Language=Default` only on the small caps font, and the solution to that turns out to be, for `babel`:

```
\documentclass[14pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[english, serbianc]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\defaultfontfeatures[XCharter]{
  UprightFont = *-Roman,
  UprightFeatures = {SmallCapsFont=*-Roman},
  BoldFont = *-Bold,
  BoldFeatures = {SmallCapsFont=*-Bold},
  ItalicFont = *-Italic,
  SlantedFont = *-Slanted,
  SlantedFeatures = {SmallCapsFont=*-Slanted},
  BoldItalicFont = *-BoldItalic,
  BoldSlantedFont = *-BoldSlanted,
  BoldSlantedFeatures = {SmallCapsFont=*-BoldSlanted},
  SmallCapsFeatures={Letters=SmallCaps},
  Extension = .otf}

% XCharter 1.221 has liga for English but not Serbian, and a language feature
% for Serbian but not English.
\babelfont{rm}
          {XCharter}
\babelfont[english]{rm}
          [Ligatures=Common, Language=Default]{XCharter}
\babelfont[serbianc]{rm}
          [Script=Cyrillic,
           Language=Serbian,
           SmallCapsFeatures={Script=Cyrillic, Language=Default, Letters=SmallCaps}
          ]{XCharter}

\babeltags{serbian=serbianc} % Enable \begin{serbian}, etc.
\babeltags{english=english}

\begin{document}

    \begin{serbian}
        \begin{abstract}
            Чича Ђорђе жваће шљиве. Његова кћи Љиља меша џем. АаБбВвГгДд \textsc{АаБбВвГгДд}.
        \end{abstract}

        \section{АаБбВвГгДд Чича Ђорђе: \textsc{АаБбВвГгДд}.}
        АаБбВвГгДд Чича Ђорђе: \textsc{АаБбВвГгДд}.
    \end{serbian}

    \begin{english}
        \section{АаБбВвГгДд Чича Ђорђе: \textsc{АаБбВвГгДд}.}
        АаБбВвГгДд Чича Ђорђе: \textsc{АаБбВвГгДд}.
        \textsc{English AaBbCc}
    \end{english}

\end{document}
```

[image: XCharter sample]

This correctly gets you your Serbian lowercase letters, along with small caps.  The equivalent for Polyglossia is:

```
\documentclass[14pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setdefaultlanguage{serbian}
\setotherlanguage{english}

\defaultfontfeatures[XCharter]{
  UprightFont = *-Roman,
  UprightFeatures = {SmallCapsFont=*-Roman},
  BoldFont = *-Bold,
  BoldFeatures = {SmallCapsFont=*-Bold},
  ItalicFont = *-Italic,
  SlantedFont = *-Slanted,
  SlantedFeatures = {SmallCapsFont=*-Slanted},
  BoldItalicFont = *-BoldItalic,
  BoldSlantedFont = *-BoldSlanted,
  BoldSlantedFeatures = {SmallCapsFont=*-BoldSlanted},
  SmallCapsFeatures={Letters=SmallCaps},
  Extension = .otf}

% XCharter 1.221 has liga for English but not Serbian, and a language feature
% for Serbian but not English.
\setmainfont[Ligatures=Common, Language=Default]{XCharter}
\newfontfamily\serbianfont{XCharter}[
  Script=Cyrillic,
  Language=Serbian,
  SmallCapsFeatures={Script=Cyrillic, Language=Default, Letters=SmallCaps}]

\begin{document}

    \begin{serbian}
        \begin{abstract}
            Чича Ђорђе жваће шљиве. Његова кћи Љиља меша џем. АаБбВвГгДд \textsc{АаБбВвГгДд}.
        \end{abstract}

        \section{АаБбВвГгДд Чича Ђорђе: \textsc{АаБбВвГгДд}.}
        АаБбВвГгДд Чича Ђорђе: \textsc{АаБбВвГгДд}.
    \end{serbian}

    \begin{english}
        \section{АаБбВвГгДд Чича Ђорђе: \textsc{АаБбВвГгДд}.}
        АаБбВвГгДд Чича Ђорђе: \textsc{АаБбВвГгДд}.
        \textsc{English AaBbCc}
    \end{english}

\end{document}
```

Another alternative that saves you from language tagging is:

```
\documentclass[14pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[nil]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\babelprovide[import=sr-Cyrl, onchar=fonts ids, main]{serbian}
\babelprovide[import=en, onchar=fonts ids]{english}

\defaultfontfeatures[XCharter]{
  UprightFont = *-Roman,
  UprightFeatures = {SmallCapsFont=*-Roman},
  BoldFont = *-Bold,
  BoldFeatures = {SmallCapsFont=*-Bold},
  ItalicFont = *-Italic,
  SlantedFont = *-Slanted,
  SlantedFeatures = {SmallCapsFont=*-Slanted},
  BoldItalicFont = *-BoldItalic,
  BoldSlantedFont = *-BoldSlanted,
  BoldSlantedFeatures = {SmallCapsFont=*-BoldSlanted},
  SmallCapsFeatures={Letters=SmallCaps},
  Extension = .otf}

% XCharter 1.221 has liga for English but not Serbian, and a language feature
% for Serbian but not English.
\babelfont{rm}
          {XCharter}
\babelfont[english]{rm}
          [Ligatures=Common, Language=Default]{XCharter}
\babelfont[serbian]{rm}
          [Script=Cyrillic,
           Language=Serbian,
           SmallCapsFeatures={Script=Cyrillic, Language=Default, Letters=SmallCaps}
          ]{XCharter}

\babeltags{serbian=serbian} % Enable \begin{serbian}, etc.
\babeltags{english=english}

\begin{document}

      \begin{abstract}
          Чича Ђорђе жваће шљиве. Његова кћи Љиља меша џем. АаБбВвГгДд \textsc{АаБбВвГгДд}.
      \end{abstract}

      \section{АаБбВвГгДд Чича Ђорђе: \textsc{АаБбВвГгДд}.}
        АаБбВвГгДд Чича Ђорђе: \textsc{АаБбВвГгДд}. ffi

    \begin{english}
        \section{АаБбВвГгДд Чича Ђорђе: \textsc{АаБбВвГгДд}.}
        АаБбВвГгДд Чича Ђорђе: \textsc{АаБбВвГгДд}.
        \textsc{English AaBbCc} ffi
    \end{english}

\end{document}
```

[image: XCharter sample]

This automatically detects whether you are typing in Latin or Cyrillic, and selects the language, font features and hyphenation patterns appropriately, without tags.  It requires LuaLaTeX, but there is also a way to do the same in XeLaTeX.

Answer (score 1):

The problem can be reduced to the following

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{XCharter}[Script=Cyrillic,]
\setsansfont{XCharter}[Script=Cyrillic,Language=Serbian]

\begin{document}
АаБбВвГгДд \textsc{АаБбВвГгДд}.
 
\sffamily 
 
АаБбВвГгДд \textsc{АаБбВвГгДд}. 

\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see adding both the cyrillic script and the serbian language disables the small caps.

The documentation of polyglossia doesn't really say how to avoid that the Language feature is used, but the following seems to work:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setmainlanguage[script=Cyrillic]{serbian}
\SetLanguageKeys{serbian}{language=Default}

\setmainfont{XCharter}

\begin{document}
АаБбВвГгДд \textsc{АаБбВвГгДд}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for providing this workaround for ```polyglossia```. Tested few examples and all other features like hyphenation and sectioning work as well.

Comment: Never mind, I found how to turn off `Language=Serbian` for small caps only.